# SQlite - Android - Foreign key syntax

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I've been trying to get foreign keys working within my Android SQLite database. I have tried the following syntax but it gives me a force close:

```
private static final String TASK_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TASK_TABLE + " (" + TASK_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + TASK_TITLE
            + " text not null, " + TASK_NOTES + " text not null, "
    + TASK_DATE_TIME + " text not null, FOREIGN KEY ("+TASK_CAT+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+" ("+CAT_ID+"));";
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? if you need to see the other table structure then I can, its just a very simple structure for the second with an ID and a name.

**Edit:**

Here is the error:

> 03-13 13:42:35.389:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>   unknown column "taskCat" in foreign
>   key definition: create table reminders
>   (_id integer primary key
>   autoincrement, task_title text not
>   null, notes text not null,
>   reminder_date_time text not null,
>   FOREIGN KEY (taskCat) REFERENCES
>   category (_id));

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You have to define your `TASK_CAT` column first and then set foreign key on it.

```
private static final String TASK_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TASK_TABLE + " (" 
        + TASK_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + TASK_TITLE + " text not null, " 
        + TASK_NOTES + " text not null, "
        + TASK_DATE_TIME + " text not null,"
        + TASK_CAT + " integer,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TASK_CAT+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+"("+CAT_ID+"));";
```

More information you can find on sqlite foreign keys [doc](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. The solution I found was to define it all in one line but with a slightly different syntax. I did this instead of the last 2 lines: 

TASK_CAT+" INTEGER REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+");";

Comment: @jetho I want to add functionallity that once the parent key deleted all child's column record should be deleted too.

Answer (score 13):

Since I cannot comment, adding this note in addition to @jethro answer.

I found out that you also need to do the FOREIGN KEY line as the last part of create the table statement, otherwise you will get a syntax error when installing your app. What I mean is, you cannot do something like this:

```
private static final String TASK_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TASK_TABLE + " (" + TASK_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + TASK_TITLE
    + " text not null, " + TASK_NOTES + " text not null, "
+ TASK_CAT + " integer,"
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+TASK_CAT+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+" ("+CAT_ID+"), "
+ TASK_DATE_TIME + " text not null);";
```

Where I put the TASK_DATE_TIME after the foreign key line.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the error description your table contains the columns (_id, tast_title, notes, reminder_date_time) and you are trying to add a foreign key from a column "taskCat" but it does not exist in your table!