# how to make a table unique to a user in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating my first app using SQLite and I am facing issues making a user's scores unique to the user. So basically, if one user inputs scores, and another user logins, all the scores will be displayed, no matter which user-inputted them. How do I fix this so that their scores are unique to the users?

Here is my database class:

```
package com.example.golfmax;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "userData.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "userData";
    private static final String USER_ID = "id";
    private static final String NAME_COL = "name";
    private static final String PASSWORD_COL = "password";
    private static final String EMAIL_COL = "email";
    private static final String TABLE_SCORES = "scoresTable";
    private static final String COURSE_NAME = "courseName";
    private static final String USER_SCORES = "scores";
    private static final String COURSE_RATING = "courseRating";
    private static final String SLOPE_RATING = "slopeRating";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String user = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + " ("
                + USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NAME_COL + " TEXT,"
                + PASSWORD_COL + " TEXT,"
                + EMAIL_COL + " TEXT UNIQUE)";
        db.execSQL(user);

        String userScores = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORES + " ("
                + COURSE_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, "
                + USER_SCORES + " REAL UNIQUE,"
                + COURSE_RATING + " REAL UNIQUE,"
                + SLOPE_RATING + " REAL UNIQUE)";
        db.execSQL(userScores);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Boolean addUserInfo(String user, String password, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME_COL, user);
        contentValues.put(PASSWORD_COL, password);
        contentValues.put(EMAIL_COL, email);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        if(result == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Boolean checkUserPass(String user, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_USERS + " where name = ? and password = ?", new String[] {user, password});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean checkUserEmail(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_USERS + " where email = ?", new String[] {email});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean checkUserInfo(String user, String password, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_USERS + " where name = ? and password = ? and email = ?", new String[] {user, password, email});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void insertScores(String courseName, int userScores, double courseRating, double slopeRating) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COURSE_NAME, courseName);
        contentValues.put(USER_SCORES, userScores);
        contentValues.put(COURSE_RATING, courseRating);
        contentValues.put(SLOPE_RATING, slopeRating);
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORES, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<UserScores> readScores() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES, null);
        ArrayList<UserScores> userScores = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userScores.add(new UserScores(cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getInt(2),
                        cursor.getDouble(3),
                        cursor.getDouble(4)));
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return userScores;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change the user scores table schema and add email col in the users table to uniquely identify user scores by using the email column.

```
String userScores = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORES + " ("
              EMAIL_COL + " TEXT UNIQUE
            + COURSE_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, "
            + USER_SCORES + " REAL UNIQUE,"
            + COURSE_RATING + " REAL UNIQUE,"
            + SLOPE_RATING + " REAL UNIQUE)";
    db.execSQL(userScores);
```

After that change insert method as below

```
 public void insertScores(String email,String courseName, int userScores, double courseRating, double slopeRating) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EMAIL_COL, email);
    contentValues.put(COURSE_NAME, courseName);
    contentValues.put(USER_SCORES, userScores);
    contentValues.put(COURSE_RATING, courseRating);
    contentValues.put(SLOPE_RATING, slopeRating);
    db.insert(TABLE_SCORES, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}
```

After that change the below method query.

```
   public ArrayList<UserScores> readScores(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_SCORES+" in (select * From "+TABLE_USERS+"where "+EMAIL_COL+"="+email+")", null);
        ArrayList<UserScores> userScores = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userScores.add(new UserScores(cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getInt(2),
                        cursor.getDouble(3),
                        cursor.getDouble(4)));
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return userScores;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. But I was asking how I could implement foreign keys into the second table. I've tried several things including yours, except now the id for TABLE_SCORES is null.

Comment: so don't use id as the primary key. use email as the primary key in the users table and add a foreign key reference to the scores table. use this reference to create the foreign key table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289861/sqlite-android-foreign-key-syntax